# Optimizing Bird Migration Challenge

Tags: ruby, algorithm, search

I am currently working on a [challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/migratory-birds/problem) where the guidelines are as follows:

> You have been asked to help study the population of birds migrating across the continent. Each type of bird you are interested in will be identified by an integer value. Each time a particular kind of bird is spotted, its id number will be added to your array of sightings. You would like to be able to find out which type of bird is most common given a list of sightings. Your task is to print the type number of that bird and if two or more types of birds are equally common, choose the type with the smallest ID number.
>
> For example, assume your bird sightings are of types `arr = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]`. There are two each of types `1` and `2`, and one sighting of type `3`. Pick the lower of the two types seen twice: type `1`.

I have written code that passes most of the tests but times out on the exceedingly large inputs, I would like your advice on how to optimize it.

My code is as follows:

```
def migratoryBirds(arr)
    sorted = Hash[arr.map { |x| [x, arr.select { |y| y==x }.count] }]
    return sorted.max_by { |k,v| v }[0]
end
```

Comment: Look at [Array#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally), which was new in Ruby v2.7. If you need to use an earlier versions of Ruby, write (as a starting point), `arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |b,h| h[b] += 1 }` or `arr.group_by(&:itself).transform_values(&:size)`. See the version of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html) that takes argument (the *default value*) but no block, [Enumerable#group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and...

Comment: ... [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) (new in Ruby 2.4). You should not use [Array#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-count) because it makes a complete pass through the array for each unique `id`. The methods I mentioned above compute that information in a single pass through the array.

Comment: Your definition text appears to be missing information: `There are two each of types and , and one sighting of type . Pick the lower of the two types seen twice: type .` Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sorted` hash can be written a bit more concise as:

```
sorted = arr.map { |x| [x, arr.count(x)] }.to_h
```

For the example array `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3]` this is equivalent to:

```
[
  [1, arr.count(1)], # counts all 1's in arr
  [1, arr.count(1)], # counts all 1's in arr (again)
  [2, arr.count(2)], # counts all 2's in arr
  [2, arr.count(2)], # counts all 2's in arr (again)
  [3, arr.count(3)]  # counts all 3's in arr
].to_h
```

Not only does it count `1` and `2` twice. It also has to traverse the entire array again for each `count` call (or `select` in your code).

A better approach is to traverse the array *once* and use a hash for counting the occurrences:

```
arr = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]

sorted = Hash.new(0)
arr.each { |x| sorted[x] += 1 }

sorted #=> {1=>2, 2=>2, 3=>1}
```

This can also be written in a single line via [`each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
sorted = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |x, h| h[x] += 1 }
#=> {1=>2, 2=>2, 3=>1}
```

Ruby 2.7 even has a dedicated method [`tally`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally) to count occurrences:

```
sorted = arr.tally
#=> {1=>2, 2=>2, 3=>1}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Stefan. Would you mind explaining what this is doing { |x,h| h[x] += 1 }?  Is x the key? Like in an array [1,2,1,3]. On iteration through index 0 be {1=>1} and on iteration index 2 it looks like this {1=>2, 2=>1}???

Comment: @thelacaning `x` is the element and `h` is the hash that was passed as an argument, i.e. `Hash.new(0)`

Comment: Thank you @Stefan